# Validation on Lightning Actions?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, custom-button, validation

I've got a button that sends a contract to Docusign, but I'd rather the Sales Rep not be able to press it unless it meets certain criteria. In Classic, I can do a Javascript button. What's the best way to handle this in Lightning?

My initial thoughts:

1. Visualforce page with redirect?
2. Page Layouts are messy and wouldn't work due to the nature of the criteria.
3. Some kind of Lightning Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new lightning feature so you can set an action from a lightning component:

[Configure Components for Custom Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm)

And this is a good example how to do that:

[Winter’17: Using a Lightning Component from an Action](https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/08/21/winter17-using-a-lightning-component-from-an-action/)

I believe this is the best practice for your requirement.